# How to auto add your ssh public key to the authorized_keys files?

Tags: linux, ssh

I am looking for the simplest set of commands you can run for adding your public key to the authorized_keys files of the root account on a remote server.

We assume that the current user has login access to the remote server and it is also listed in the sudoers file.

Running the command twice should have no effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about running the ssh-copy-id command?  Man pages says the following:

> ssh-copy-id  -  install  your  public  key in a remote machine's authorized_keys

Sounds exactly what you're looking for?  I have never tried running the command twice, though.  It may not check for that.

Comment: While this tool seems to be the one supposed to do that, its design seems to fail this use-case. If you cannot login as root, but you can login as yourself, because the system is using NIS. Still, you are in sudoers so you could add yourself to the list. `ssh-copy-id` looks useless on any system that has password login disabled, something quite common these days.

Comment: True.  If I were to setup a new system, I would enable password login, use ssh-copy-id for myself, and then turn off password login.  Likewise, if you are a sysadmin, you can sudo to a new user's account and copy their public key to their directory in the same way.  Why bother?  Well, all it does is substitute several keystrokes.  But it also checks the permission of the authorized_keys file, etc. for you.  Sort of double-checking for you.  In that sense, it isn't "useless".  I use it all the time...

Comment: Just thought of something -- if you are so concerned about security that you would disable password login, I would disable remote root login first.  And let users who want remote root access to use sudo.  'root' is the standard system administrator login; might as well disable it so that no one bothers trying to remote login.

Comment: yead, sure disable root login for admin when server is running on NIS, is just asking for trouble when NIS is down. Root has it purpose, as you stated, and it happens to be the sysadmin :D